# Can this "curvy" region be replicated in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to replicate this picture (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Jacobian_determinant_and_distortion.svg)) with TikZ:
[image]

The part on the left is straightforward but I'm struggling to come up with ideas for the part on the right.

Comment: This can be achieved rather easily, either with projections from 3D, nonlinear transformations or just by hand.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat what do you mean “projections from 3D” ?

Comment: @BlackMild You can draw something in 3D and project it on the screen. The pic on the right looks a bit like a surface in 3D.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This employs a nonlinear transformation to produce a similar output.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{191,202,236}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{185,134,146}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\makeatletter 
\def\curvytransformation{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\pgf@x+0.3*\pgf@y-3*sin(\pgf@y*2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\pgf@y-10*sin(\pgf@x)}%
\pgf@x=\myx pt%
\pgf@y=\myy pt%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
 \begin{scope}[xshift=-10cm,local bounding box=L]
  \draw[fill=myblue] (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,8);
  \draw[thick,fill=myred] (1,1) rectangle (7,7);
  \draw[help lines] (1,1) grid (7,7);
  \draw[very thick,<->] (1,7) |- (7,1);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=R]
  \pgftransformnonlinear{\curvytransformation}%
  \draw[fill=myblue] (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (8,8);
  \draw[thick,fill=myred] (1,1) rectangle (7,7);
  \draw[help lines] (1,1) grid (7,7);
  \path (1,1) coordinate (o) (1,1.1) coordinate (y) (1.1,1) coordinate (x);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.2] let \p1=($(y)-(o)$),\p2=($(x)-(o)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)} in
  [fill=white,fill opacity=0.2] (o) -- ++(\n1:6.25) coordinate (y')  
  -- ++(\n2:6.25) -- ++(\n1+180:6.25) coordinate (x')
  -- cycle;
 \draw[very thick,<->] (y') -- (o) -- (x');
 %
 \draw[-stealth,thick] (-1.5,4) to[bend left=10] node[above]{$f$} (0.5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer!! Can you write the expression of the nonlinear transformation, please? Thank you, as always.

Comment: @manooooh It is all in the code. `(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)` gets mapped to `(\pgf@x+0.3*\pgf@y-3*sin(\pgf@y*2), \pgf@y-10*sin(\pgf@x))`.

Comment: As usual excellent answer !